# didn't know symbol "+=" in android

Tags: android, json

i have a little problem with my code

here is my code

```
public class LihatInfo extends Activity {
   
   TextView error,br1;
   String i,id_kepadatan,returnString;
   
   
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   
   @Override
   
   
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.lihat_info);
       
        br1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.berita1);
       
        
      
       
        
   }
   
   public void clickHandler(View view){
    Intent a = null;
    id_kepadatan = "1";
    switch (view.getId()){
    case R.id.lihatInfo:
        
ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        
        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id_kepadatan", id_kepadatan));
           
        
/*            String valid = "1";*/      
        
        String response = null;
        
        try {
           
           response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/android/lihatInfo.php", postParameters);
           
           
           String result = response.toString();  
           //parse json data

              try{
                      returnString = "";


                JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
                      for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){

                              JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                              Log.i("log_tag","id_kepadatan: "+json_data.getInt("id_kepadatan")+
                                      ", username: "+json_data.getString("username")+
                                      ", nama_jalan: "+json_data.getString("nama_jalan")+
                                      ", status: "+json_data.getString("status")+
                                      ", tanggal: "+json_data.getString("tanggal")+
                                      ", waktu: "+json_data.getString("waktu")+
                                      ", keterangan: "+json_data.getString("keterangan")
                              );

                              //Get an output to the screen
                              returnString += "\n" + json_data.getString("nama_jalan") + " mengalami "+ json_data.getString("status")+ " pada "+ json_data.getString("tanggal")+ " waktu "+ json_data.getString("waktu")+ " karena "+ json_data.getString("keterangan");
                      }
              }


              catch(JSONException e){
                      Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
              }

              try{


               br1.setText(returnString);


              }


              catch(Exception e){

               Log.e("log_tag","Error in Display!" + e.toString());;          

              }   

         }

               catch (Exception e) {

          Log.e("log_tag","Error in http connection!!" + e.toString());     

         }
        break;
        
    case R.id.cariPeta2:
        a = new Intent(this,MainActivity2.class);
        startActivity(a);
        break;
   case R.id.kembali2:
        a = new Intent(this, Menu.class);
        startActivity(a);
        break;
}
   }
    
    
}
```

what i want to ask is

1. what the meaning of symbol  `+=` in line

   `returnString += "\n" + json_data.getString("nama_jalan") + " mengalami "+ json_data.getString("status")+ " pada "+ json_data.getString("tanggal")+ " waktu "+ json_data.getString("waktu")+ " karena "+ json_data.getString("keterangan");`
2. can i replace `String returnString`  with this  `String[] returnString`  ? because i want to use ListView, not using TextView like my code above.....

that's all i want to ask.....for every help, i will much appreciate it

Thank You :)

Comment: `a += b` is shorthand for `a = a + b`.

Comment: you want to convert from string to stringarray for post values in listview ??

Comment: TechEnd : Yes....can i do that?

Comment: Its "analyse the other users code for" question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**+=** Symbol is used for the appending text .

> ADD - AND assignment operator, It adds right operand to the left operand
>   and assign the result to left operand

Comment: one more question....can i replace String "returnString" to String[] "returnString" ? because i want to use ListView

Comment: @Safarudin yes you can , but then after you can not use += operator, you have to user returnString[0] = json_data.getString("nama_jalan");
returnString[1] = json_data.getString("status");

Comment: what if i use returnString[0] = json_data.getString("nama_jalan") + json_data.getString("status") +.....

then returnString[1] = json_data.getString("nama_jalan") + json_data.getString("status") +.....

it will be fine or not?

Comment: Then it will show only Repeated text in listview.